# Съезжает строчка матрицы Java

Tags: java, матрицы

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        int[][] matrix = new int[x][x];
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Имеется типичный код для вывода матрицы на экран , но на выходе верхние строчки съезжают. В чем причина?

[image: Вывод:]

Comment: МБ потому, что верхние две строчки преимущественно состоят из однозначных чисел, а остальные - из двузначных?

Comment: да, так и есть, проблемы с выводом решается если двузначные числа вверху, но как сделать чтобы было универсальным ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема с выводом в вашей конкретной консоли. Попробуйте в другой, все должно работать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: странно. На маке тоже нормально отображает, а на двух виндах не выводит.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();
int[][] matrix = new int[x][x];
int count = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = count++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
        System.out.print((matrix[i][j] > 9 ? "" : " ") + matrix[i][j] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: У вас пустой литерал после тренарного оператора. На стадии компиляции еще умрет